# RDLC report not displaying footer when tablix to large

Tags: c#, winforms, rdlc

I'm having some problems with a RDLC report in a WinForms application. I created a report with header, footer and a simple tablix with column headers and a details group where I have a list of data. The data gets imported via code, not via a dataset.

But I have two problems:

1. When the details group becomes to large it doesn't continue on a second page when needed.
2. My page footer doesn't show when the details group expands past the regular body. It might be that the two problems are related. But I just can't figure it out.

Below you can find screenshot of the designer.

[image]

If there is need for more information please let me know.

Comment: What do you mean by "when the details group becomes to large it doesn't continue on a second page when needed"?

Comment: @InitKnit That when the table becomes to large to fit on one page, it doesn't create a second page, for all the information to be shown, but just hide the information that doesn't fit.

Comment: Is all the data that is "hidden" are in the same textbox? Did you check off option to allow text area to expand (CanGrow property)?

Comment: No not all the data in is one textbox, but it's a tablix which gets filled with a dataset. So that won't be solution.